# Issue with dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

i'm stuck with this dropdown which don't work...

I'have a PHP application , and i used to create a file included everywhere in my app , it contains the menu.

I probably forget to include some files, idk.
Here my `<head>`

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

So , i include the jQuery lib , the css files ,and the bootstrap.js.. what's wrong ?

Notice that this snippet work in an other application, i just change some things like links.. That's why i suppose to have forget something :/

Here the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gQ7HF/

Do you see something hurting your eyes ? A so hudge error that i don't notice it ?

Thanks by advance ! :)

PS : i'm on Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remove the js code an just let fiddle supply the bootstrap.js it works like a charm. Have your change something in the code? Try to use a cdn für the bootstrap.js ... it should work

good luck

Comment: Nop , i'haven't change anything , and it's working in the source app. I'm going to recheck for the file on the web

Comment: With a CDN it's work fine, no idea why it's working in an other server with the local file.. Thanks a lot !